# How to push data from custom HTML form into Sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, html, forms, list, sharepoint

I´be been searching this for some time now and have not found a working solution yet.. I have custom form written in HTML (it is quite big and complicated) and some rules in JS attached to it and what I need is to insert it into iframe (web content editor) in SP and push the data into existing list on the same site.. I have found some JS libraries like SPservices and Sharepoint plus but was not able to make it work..

I cannot use infopath unfortunately - otherwise it would be easy.

Does anybody know how to do it or give me some simple example of code?

Thanks in advance!!!

Edit:

So I have this simple html form inserted using web content editor is SP:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/list.js"></script>



Nadpis: <input type="text" id="nadpis"> <br>
Text: <input type="text" id="text"> <p></p>
<input type="button" value="Odeslat" id="submit">
```

and this is list.js

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

  var vnadpis = document.getElementById("nadpis").value;
  var vtext = document.getElementById("text").value;

  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Test");
  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  var oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
  oListItem.set_item("Nadpis",vnadpis);
  oListItem.set_item("Text",vtext);
  oListItem.update();
  ctx.load(oListItem);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
  Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("Success!")}),
  Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("Error!")}));
}


});
```

but nothing happens.. suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any error message in browser console ? If yes, please share that error message.

Comment: @RohitWaghela nope, I am not getting a thing.. thats strange.. no errors, even no warnings and messages.. :/

Comment: You can use REST as well

Comment: @Vaibhav i dont really understand that.. :(

Comment: @TomášVítů Give me some time. I will share an example with you. See if you find this helpful https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0759f523-8bb4-4d4b-8587-493c160904fd/sharepoint-2013-powershell-script-to-add-listitem-using-rest?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: @Vaibhav I tried to put it there but I have some "undefined" errors.. :/

Comment: now I have error via console.log.. {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"cs-CZ\",\"value\":\"The property 'Nadpis' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.TestListItem'.

Comment: @TomášVítů lets do screenshare and solve your issue. ping me on Skype : vaibhav.chorge1

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate it.. I added you to the contact list, pls accept

Answer (score 1):

try to wrap your code inside `$( document ).ready()`. So that your code will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Refer below code. It will work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function() {

        var vnadpis = document.getElementById("nadpis").value;
        var vtext = document.getElementById("text").value;

        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Test");
            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem.set_item("Nadpis", vnadpis);
            oListItem.set_item("Text", vtext);
            oListItem.update();
            ctx.load(oListItem);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
                    alert("Success!")
                }),
                Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {
                    alert("Error!")
                }));
        });


    });
});
```

**HTML -->**

Note - Change JS reference path accordingly. And try to reference JS files in this sequence.

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/list.js"></script>



Nadpis: <input type="text" id="nadpis"> <br>
Text: <input type="text" id="text"> <p></p>
<input type="button" value="Odeslat" id="submit">
```

Comment: so now I know where there was no response, I had bad paths to js files.. now I can see in console, that they are loaded and suddenly it gives me an error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'set_formDigestHandlingEnabled' in sp.js file..

Comment: and two more errors while loading page.. syntax error in index.aspx where content web editor is inserted (var navBarHelpOverrideKey = &quot;WSSEndUser&quot;;) - undefined and in scriptresource.axd (: Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined.
Parameter name: baseType)

Comment: @TomášVítů Try to add reference to `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `sp.runtime.js` as well. Refer my updated answer for sequence of JS files.

Comment: so I have managed to achieve that it gives me no errors BUT when I click on "submit" - nothing happens.. maybe I will try to change how I call the function to onclick

Comment: OK. But If you write your javascript to bind `onclick` event inside `$(document).ready()` then it should work. Anyway you can try to write `onclick` directly in your control inline and check if it works.

Comment: so I changed it I call the fuction via onclick event on button and it says it is undefined, but I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

It is like a cooking recipe. It is fairly easy. Following example takes the List "MyList" and adds a new Item with title "MyNewItem" to it. Make sure you included the necessary sharepoint javascript libraries.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
  var oListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
  oListItem.set_item("Title","MyNewItem");
  oListItem.update();
  ctx.load(oListItem);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("Success!")}),
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("Error!")}));
}
```

So just replace the string with your input value (retrieved by plain JS or with jQuery)

Comment: thanks a lot.. so "title" is the name of a field in SP and "MyNewItem" is value of a field in my form ok? and what are those sp js libraries? sp.js?

Comment: so I created something (see above) but it doesnt work.. :(